# Crypto JS not encrypting properly in production mode

Tags: react-native, encryption, expo, cryptojs

I've the following code to send a message:

```
function sendMessage(data) {
        data.version = clientVersion;
        var message = { data: CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(data), system.Authentication.SendAuth, { mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7, iv: system.Authentication.Sendiv }).toString() };
        return JSON.stringify(message);
    }
```

This works just fine on dev mode. Expo app sends the encrypted message and gets decrypted properly. However, in production mode, the encrypted code gets sent and received no problem, but when decrypted by the server we get a negative sigBytes number. So the decryption failed.

This happened when updation from SDK 27 to SDK 31 of expo.

Comment: You can try upgrade crypto.js